# Problema al intentar usar React-Router-Dom

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

Estoy clonando un proyecto de React de un repo de mi cuenta de github para continuarlo. Al intentar añadir componentes de react-router-dom tengo este problema.
Failed to compile ./src/components/App/App.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom'.

Busqué como añadir react-router-dom y probé instalarlo siguiendo las respuestas de este post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53914013/failed-to-compile-module-not-found-cant-resolve-react-router-dom.

Sin embargo, al iniciar el comando 'npm run start' obtengo el siguiente error

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

He chequeado la versión de React en caso que sea el problema 3, pero figura una sola versión.
Estoy seguro que los hooks que estoy usando están bien, ya que funcionaban antes de instalar react-router-dom.
Estoy casi seguro que el problema es el primero, hay un conflicto entre React-Dom y React-Router-Dom. En mi dependecias figura lo siguiente:

```
 "dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.1",
"@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
"axios": "^0.21.1",
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
"web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
```

He intentado reinstalar React y no hay caso. Sigo teniendo ese problema. Ya he intentado dos veces, clonando de nuevo el mismo repo. Ayuda!!! Gracias

Comment: instala de nuevo react router, o borra la carpeta node modules y dale npm install o yarn add o install algo asi. cualquiera de las 2 para instalar todas las dependencias de nuevo

Answer (score 0):

intenta borrar la carpeta node_modules de la carpeta raíz del proyecto y luego ejecuta npm install, también trata de reinstalar React router y por ultimo chequea esto:
**Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function.** revisa de donde estas llamando al hook, revisa tambien que no se haya auto importado algo, chequea que tus importaciones sean justo las que necesitas. suerte!.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar borrando package-lock.json y ejecutar

```
npm install
```

o actualizando el nodejs y el npm:
https://nodejs.org/en/

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```